# Message box jquery in asp.net (old style)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, message

I have a asp.net user control, I added a image button and then in head I am using javascript/jquery to add a button event to it, so that it will show a message box on button click, now if I look into developers tools I can see CSS is loaded but when I click on image button all happens is a page refresh, now if I try to add `alert("Message");` instead of my function it does work.

I would prefer to do it in front end.

```
<head id="head1">
   <link href="/_LAYOUTS/1033/STYLES/abc/arts/galdtor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[id$='btnSE']").click(function() {
          $('body').append("<div id='M'><span id='text'></span><br/><div id='BPB' onclick='return BPB();'><a href='' onclick='return BPB();'></a></div></div>");
        });

       function BPB() {
         $('#M').remove();
         $('#EM').remove();
         return false;
       }
     });
  </script>

</head>
```

then in body I got this,

```
<div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px; float: left;">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSE" runat="server" ImageUrl="/_LAYOUTS/1033/IMAGES/abc/arts/gtor/ow.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
 <div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px; float: left;">
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSE" runat="server"   OnClientClick="doWork(); return false;"
 ImageUrl="/_LAYOUTS/1033/IMAGES/abc/arts/gtor/ow.png" />
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doWork() {  
  $('body').prepend("<div id='M'><span id='text'></span><br/><div id='BPB'     onclick='return BPB();'>
 <a href='' onclick='return BPB();'></a>
 </div></div>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: You must prevent the postback by returning false

Comment: Only thing I would say, your a life saver, working now like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='' onclick='return BPB();'>
```

try

```
<a href='javascript:bool(BPB());'></a>
```

since you r not setting anything in the href the page will reload